# Creating an overload which returns a different type based off a boolean value (e.g. via generics)?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a function that returns an array as chunks:

```
extension Array {
  func chunked(ofCount chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
    stride(from: 0, to: count, by: chunkSize).map {
      Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + chunkSize, count)])
    }
  }
}
```

I now want to create an overload that allows the consumer to auto fill the last chunk with nils: (Notice the return type has changed to `[[Element?]]`)

```
extension Array {
  func chunked(ofCount chunkSize: Int, fillWithNils: Bool) -> [[Element?]] {
    ...
  }
}
```

If a consumer uses `chunked(ofCount: 4, fillWithNils: true)` the result will correctly be `[[Element?]]`. However, if they pass `chunked(ofCount: 4, fillWithNils: false)`, it will return the same type, when it should have returned `[[Element]]` instead, since the method should not have returned nils.

I realize one way to fix this is to not use an overload and append the method name instead:

```
extension Array {
  func chunkedAndFillWithNils(ofCount chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element?]] {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, this isn't as discoverable and doesn't allow the consumer to use a variable to control the behavior.

---

Is there a way to use protocols and/or associated types to create overloads where the call site looks similar to this?

```
let noNils: [[String]] = strings.chunked(ofCount: 4, with: NoNils.self)
let yesNils: [[String?]] = strings.chunked(ofCount: 4, with: YesNils.self)

let behavior: ChunkedBehavior = ...
let dynamicNils = strings.chunked(ofCount: 4, with: behavior)
```

I tried implementing this but got stuck when trying to make the chunked generics type equal the ChunkedBehavior `associatedtype`.

```
protocol ChunkedBehavior {
  associatedtype Element
  associatedtype ResultElement
}

enum NoNils: ChunkedBehavior { // type 'NoNils' does not conform to protocol 'ChunkedBehavior'
  typealias ResultElement = Element
}

enum YesNils: ChunkedBehavior {
  typealias ResultElement = Optional<Element>
}

extension Array {
  func chunked<C: ChunkedBehavior>(ofCount: Int, behavior: C) -> [[C.ResultElement]] where C.Element == Element {
    return [[]]
  }
}
```

Comment: And what type would `dynamicNils` have? Note that types are resolved at *compile time.*

Comment: This is impossible. Swift does not have dependent types (types based on values). You'll need to redesign not to require this.

Comment: I was expecting `dynamicNils: ChunkedBehavior` but perhaps the `associatedtype` means it can only be used as a generic, right?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative of naming it `chunkedAndFillWithNils(ofCount:)`, but essentially acts the same, is to create these general enums:

```
enum TrueOnly {
  case `true`
}

enum FalseOnly {
  case `false`
}
```

You could then create overloads like this:

```
func chunked(ofCount chunkSize: Int, fillWithNils: TrueOnly) -> [[Element?]] {}

func chunked(ofCount chunkSize: Int, fillWithNils: FalseOnly) -> [[Element]] {}
```

Since there is no type that encompasses a `TrueOnly` and a `FalseOnly` value, you still cannot have the `dynamicNils` behavior as outlined in the question. Even if you attempt to create a shared protocol, you'll run into problems:

```
protocol SingleBool {}
protocol SingleBoolTrue: SingleBool {}
protocol SingleBoolFalse: SingleBool {}
enum TrueOnly: SingleBoolTrue { case `true` }
enum FalseOnly: SingleBoolFalse { case `false` }

extension Array {
  func chunked(ofCount chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] { [] }
  func chunked<T: SingleBool>(ofCount chunkSize: Int, fillWithNils: T) -> [[Element?]] where T: SingleBoolTrue { [] }
  func chunked<T: SingleBool>(ofCount chunkSize: Int, fillWithNils: T) -> [[Element]] where T: SingleBoolFalse { [] }
}

let dynamicBehavior: SingleBool = FalseOnly.false
let test: [[Int]] = [1, 2, 3].chunked(ofCount: 2, fillWithNils: dynamicBehavior) // ❌ Instance method 'chunked(ofCount:fillWithNils:)' requires that 'T' conform to 'SingleBoolFalse'
```